# 502 Bad Gateway nginx

Tags: python, django, docker

I wanted to add indexes to optimize sql queries, after adding I start the server and get

```
    nginx-proxy_1  | nginx.1     | 2021/07/02 12:50:43 [error] 40#40: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: api.localhost, request: "GET /api/procurements/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.2:80/api/procurements/", host: "api.localhost"
nginx-proxy_1  | nginx.1     | api.localhost 172.19.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2021:12:50:43 +0000] "GET /api/procurements/ HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36" "172.19.0.2:80"
```

[image]

After, I canceled all the changes, returned everything as it was, i completely stop the whole process with Ctrl + C, then I raise the server with `docker-compose up`, but I still get **502 Bad Gateway**

I absolutely do not understand anything in the project and I do not know which files to show you to make it easier for you to understand what the problem is, but I am always in touch and will throw off any files, just tell me

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=ims
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ims
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  api:
    build: api
    environment:
      - DATABASE_NAME=ims
      - DATABASE_USER=ims
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=ims
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - web-media:/opt/cron-ims/api/media/
      - web-staticfiles:/opt/cron-ims/api/staticfiles/
  www:
    build: www
    depends_on:
      - api
  pos:
    build: pos
    depends_on:
      - api

volumes:
  db-data:
  web-media:
  web-staticfiles:
```

Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: can you add your docker-compose.yaml and any Nginx configuration files please? cheers

Comment: senior programmer solved this problem, thanks

@NoamYizraeli

Comment: Could you answer your question with the solution?

Comment: I just inserted the wrong line in the wrong place when I added an index in the class to optimize sql queries, which is why 502 appeared